# How to solve app crashing on kivymd screen

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I have a simple kivy app that uses some elements of kivymd, like a date picker and toolbar. In the apk all the app works fine but when I switch to a screen that uses a KivyMD element it crashes.

This is my spec file req:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1, sqlite3,pillow
```

I've tried to change the versions of both kivy and kivyMD but nothing has worked, and logacat doesnt throw an error when it crashes it just does. Does anyone know why?